# Dynamically display ImageView with Multi-line Linear Layout

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I am going to put ImageView inside the LinearLayout dynamically (in code) I only have this LinearLayout defined in my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/pictures"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:singleLine="false"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</LinearLayout>
```

Currently, the LinearLayout only display 1 line of images. The remaining images are gone. What should I put inside the code such that the LinearLayout will automatically jump to a new line and load all the images? Eg: 3 images per line for 4 lines?

[image] [image] [image] [image] 
[image] [image] [image] [image] 
[image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use `ListView` instead of `LinearLayout`.
Because `ListView` provides you to add same type of `View`s as an `Item` inside.

To do stuff,

1) http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html 
2) http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/ 
3) http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html 
4) http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: I have heard about the ListView.. However I would like to implement a Photo Gallery kind of application as updated in my above question.

Comment: then you just need to create `ImageView` having fixed hight and width, and add to `LinearLayout` by its method `addView()`